# Manipulate RSSI value

Tags: python, bluetooth

My issue is pretty simple to explain: I doing some tests with my Raspberry and Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). I bought a Bluetooth 4.0 dongle and everything is setup fine.
Now for a little project, I need to retrieve the RSSI value from a beacon that is advertising nearby (guess for what purpose). The way I found to do so is a simple pipeline:
`sudo hcidump -a | grep rssi | awk '{print $2}'`
Making it being preceded from `sudo hcitool lescan &> /dev/null` makes the trick: I get printed at screen continuously the RSSI of the beacon nearby.
And that is the problem: continuously. I would like to be able to manipulate this value within a shell script or a python script. The most simple result I can be happy with is to create a csv file with the time stamp and the RSSI value

I hope to have explained clearly ;)

Comment: Do you have any sample output? Appending `| head -1` to the end could do it (to get the first line)...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. As you pointed out, first run the hcitool in the background:
       `sudo hcitool lescan --duplicates`
   Note the use of "duplicates" so we keep on logging the changing RSSI value of the BLE device
2. Create a script (tester.sh) and insert the following code:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   while read address
   do
       read RSSI
       timestamp=`date`
       echo "$timestamp,$address,$RSSI"
   done
   ```

in the above we're basically waiting for to lines from stdin (that's the 'read' lines). The first line containing 'read' is the MAC address of the device, the second 'read' line is to get the RSSI value. I also inserted the timestamp just for a more comprehensive answer

3. Now we use bash pipes to feed in the information we need like so:

   ```
   sudo hcidump -a | egrep 'RSSI|bdaddr' | cut -f 8 -d ' ' | ./tester.sh > /tmp/result.csv
   ```

All we're doing here is using HCIDUMP, then egrep to filter out the lines containing the device address and the RSSI. The output of the egrep command is prepended with a tab, so in the subsequent cut command we have to use the 8th field to get what we're after since i'm separating on ' '. Last we feed this into our script which processes the values and output them in csv format. I then just redirect the output into the csv file

To manipulate the RSSI value you just need to modify the tester.sh file as needed.